# Why are the columns of my primefaces dataTable are not rendered?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

following p:dataTable with dynamic columns:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{searchMaskBL.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}" var="curRow">
    <p:columns value="#{curRow.getColumns()}" var="curColumn">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{curColumn.label} #{curColumn.colonOnRightSide ? ':' : ''}" for="colInputTextId" />
        <h:inputText id="colInputTextId" value="" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

The iteration over the rows defined with #{searchMaskBL.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()} works, but #{curRow.getColumns()} is never called. Also curRow.columns does not work. What' wrong? The ui model has rows and columns.

Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the columns value attribute iterate over the current row...

According to the [columns example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml) in the PF showcase, you should it like this (but adapt it to your scenario:

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{dtColumnsView.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable" filteredValue="#{dtColumnsView.filteredCars}">                   
    <p:columns value="#{dtColumnsView.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{car[column.property]}" filterBy="#{car[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Where you populate a columns model and iterate over that in the value attribute of the colums tag

Comment: But this means I cannot have a different amount of columns for each row? The columns amount is dynamic, but for each row the same, isn't it?

Comment: Correct...The only thing you can have is empty values then for certain columns, but you cannot realy different amount of colums (header wise this would also be a 'problem'

Comment: Have done it with p:panelGrid and colspan and ui:repeat to draw a dynamic label/input component mask ui driven by a model